# Difference between iptables default policy to `DROP` and inserting a seperate policy in input chain to DROP all connections

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, rhel-5

I'm trying to DROP all incoming connections to my server, except from particular networks. At the same time I want to keep all outgoing connections from my server to external network (any network over any protocol) open. It is working by making below two changes in INPUT chain:

*Note: the testing was done with 3 servers (VMs) with IPs on 192.168.0.0/24 network, and all rules defined on server3 (IP: 192.168.0.3)*

```
a. iptables -P INPUT DROP
b. iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
[root@server3 ~]# iptables -nvL

Chain INPUT (policy DROP 124 packets, 22308 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  265 34603 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 433 packets, 34693 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

However, my first question:

1. When I defined the first rule above (changing the default policy for INPUT chain), it stopped all outgoing connections(ssh , ping) from my server(IP: 192.168.0.3) as well. Why is this happening, if my default OUTPUT chain policy is still accept, and I don't have any rules defined under OUTPUT chain?

I wanted to achieve same thing by not changing the default policy for INPUT chain, like this:

```
c. iptables -I INPUT -j DROP
d. iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

But it still blocks all incoming/outgoing connections to/from my server3. This brings me to my second question:

2. How are the rules `c.` and `a.` working differently ? Kindly help in understanding, as I'm new to linux firewalls.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a default DROP INPUT policy, even the **response** packets from your outgoint connections will get dropped.

To accept those, add this input rule:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

As for your last question, in your `c and d` example (assuming empty rules before those commands) you are setting a first rule `drop everything` and a **second** rule that would accept traffic from a certain network. IPTABLES grabs a match as soon as it can, so the first rule always matches (no condition set) so every rule after that won't execute. Exceptions to a rule must be defined **before** the rule.

In the first example `-P INPUT DROP`, you are setting a **last** rule that will catch whatever was not matched before, so any exception added will be executed before that default rule (`-P`).

`-I`  inserts into a certain position (for example, in my previous command, I am setting the ESTABLISHED,RELATED rule to be the first so it matches no matter what you set after that.

`-A`  appends to the rule list, so if will be matched just before the default.

If you want to achieve the same as the first example with explicit rules (like `c and d`), you should exchange possitions of those.

Comment: thanks so much for the elaborate explanation. Now the importance of the `order` of the rules in each CHAIN is more clear. One more query relating to the `rule` that you suggested. Will it behave same as: `iptables -I INPUT 1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`?

Comment: It's the same. `State` is "older" and it seems that `conntrack` will be the standard on newer kernels. See http://serverfault.com/questions/358996/iptables-whats-the-difference-between-m-state-and-m-conntrack for more detailed explanation.

Comment: @NuTTyX My default policy of input is drop, but there are rules that allows packets, same as the one you defined. More details of the iptable rules that I have added can be found here https://0wned.it/2016/07/30/creating-a-highly-interactive-honeypot-with-honssh/#targetText=Real%20systems%20that%20are%20instrumented,real%20threat%20to%20an%20organisation. But problem is that I cannot access internet.

Comment: Solved my Kubernetes routing problem by applying to the FORWARD chain, that by some process gets set to default DROP.  -I FORWARD 1 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT